# why my foreach loop is not working with all rows

Tags: laravel

i have problem with for each loop that must get value from table and get sum and count from other tables depends on selected row in loop

here is my code :

```
$flights = Basic::all();

    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
       if($flight->cur_allowed_seats > '0'){
           $basics_id = Basic::find($flight->id);
           $inf_count = Ticket::where([['sector',$flight->sector],['pass_type','3'],['flight_date',$flight->flight_date]])->get()->count();
           $child_count = Ticket::where([['sector',$flight->sector],['pass_type','2'],['flight_date',$flight->flight_date]])->get()->count();
           $total_sale = DB::table('tickets')
               ->where([['sector', $flight->sector],['flight_date',$flight->flight_date]])
               ->sum('sale');
           $free_seats_per1= DB::table('basics')->where('id', $flight->id)->first()->cur_total_seats;
           $free_seats_per2= DB::table('basics')->where('id', $flight->id)->first()->total_seats;
           $free_seats_per=$free_seats_per1/$free_seats_per2*100;
           return view('home', array('flights' => $flights,'basics_id' => $basics_id,'inf_count' => $inf_count,
               'child_count' => $child_count,'total_sale' => $total_sale,'free_seats_per' => $free_seats_per,
           ));
       }
```

and here is blade code :

```
  <div class="content-body">
            @foreach($flights as $flight)
            <h1 class="content-header-title mb-0">{{ $flight->sector }} <span style="color: red">{{ $flight->flight_date }}</span></h1>
            <!-- eCommerce statistic -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-12">
                    <div class="card pull-up">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="media d-flex">
                                    <div class="media-body text-left">
                                        <h3 class="info" >{{ $flight->cur_total_seats }}</h3>
                                        <h6  style="font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">المقاعد الشاغرة بحائل</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="icon-flag info font-large-2 float-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mt-1 mb-0 box-shadow-2">
                                    {{--                                        {{ format_number((($basics_has->cur_total_seats/$basics_has->total_seats) * 100), 2) }}%--}}
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-gradient-x-info" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ $free_seats_per }}%"
                                         aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-12">
                    <div class="card pull-up">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="media d-flex">
                                    <div class="media-body text-left">
                                        <h3 class="info" >{{ $child_count }}</h3>
                                        <h6  style="font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">عدد الأطفال المحجوز بحائل</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>

                                        <i class="icon-user-following info font-large-2 float-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mt-1 mb-0 box-shadow-2">

                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-gradient-x-info" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ $flight->percent }}%"
                                         aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-12">
                    <div class="card pull-up">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="media d-flex">
                                    <div class="media-body text-left">
                                        <h3 class="success">{{$inf_count}}</h3>
                                        <h6 style="font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">عدد الرضع المحجوز بحائل</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="la la-user success font-large-2 float-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mt-1 mb-0 box-shadow-2">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-gradient-x-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%"
                                         aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-12">
                    <div class="card pull-up">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="media d-flex">
                                    <div class="media-body text-left">
                                        <h3 class="danger">{{$total_sale}}</h3>
                                        <h6 style="font-size:12px;font-weight: bold">إجمالي مبيعات حائل</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <i class="la la-dollar danger font-large-2 float-right"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress progress-sm mt-1 mb-0 box-shadow-2">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-gradient-x-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 85%"
                                         aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

@endforeach

```
        </div>
```

my problem is that any value from any table except 'Basic' it return only one value not loop
can any one help me with this issue please ?

Comment: Your return your query inside the foreach loop, so only first query will return, then the loop will stop.

Comment: maybe because you are `return`ing in the first iteration of the `foreach` loop in the controller?

Comment: so what is the right way to make it ?

Comment: You should return your query outside the foreach loop

Comment: and adjust the assignment of all those variables as they would keep getting overwritten every iteration

Comment: it cannot be outside the loop because parameters will be not defined

Comment: are you intending to have `$flights` only contain flights where `cur_allowed_seats > 0`?

Comment: Yes 'Basic' table contains flights but there is other table 'Tickets' contains the issued tickets so i need the loop to get every flight and calculate how many tickets issued and how much money

Comment: every flight, or only flights with `cur_allowed_seats > 0`?  and is there any reason that a `ticket` isn't related to a `basic` by a `basic_id` field?

Comment: you are comparing to a string `> '0'` instead of a number `> 0`